# Strange jQuery error in IE: Unexpected call to method or property access

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

Like allways, in Firefox, Chrome, Safari and Opera everything works without a problem. But IE... This is another story :)

Here is my full code: http://pastebin.com/ZdzzFayJ

At least one thing good in IE, come to me with the following error:

```
SCRIPT65535: Unexpected call to method or property access. 
jquery.min.js, line 3 character 29586
```

What is wrong? I can't find a bug :(

---

**UPDATE**

I cleaned up my code, javascript functions are now called as a jQuery plugin. I am still getting an error, but now I know where.

In my code I put a comment `IE ERROR` next to the code where IE alert the error message.

PLUGINS: http://pastebin.com/6Dnd1qtd

jQuery : http://pastebin.com/wiHALjZx

I have no idea why IE breaks there.. Any solutions?

---

Regards, Mario

Comment: You really need to test those functions in isolation and determine which one is giving you trouble; then maybe we can identify an errant line. Asking us to go on a scavenger hunt through all that code is not a good idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem in the following way:

- Clean up my code ( [JSHint](http://www.jshint.com/) was very helpful! )
- Before anything I included `"//html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"` to IE recognize that I am using HTML5 tags such as section, header,...
- In jQuery plugin I fill element with html content. Instead of using `$(defaultOpts.data_container).html("HTML CONTENT")` I use `defaultOpts.data_container.html("HTML CONTENT")`. So I send  object element `$(#ID)` in parameter to plugin instead of sending just element ID `"#ID"`.

Now, everything working OK. Thank you all for your support and effort.

Comment: I was getting a similar error when calling jQuery addOption(), and html5shiv v3.4 was actually the problem - upgrading it fixed the issue.

Comment: I actually found that adding type="text/javascript" to the script tags helped, but only in IE8

Answer (score 3):

For me the problem was the following:

i use a lib where is applied on all environment.

my_lib.js

```
jQuery.ajax({
        data : jQuery('form').serialize(),
        url : '/'+action[1]+'/post_form',
        type : 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){
            $('#my_name_id').find('option').remove().end().append(data.select_options);

});
```

Json returns:

```
select_options  "<option></option>"
```

Everything is fine! BUT, in one form #my_name_id is not a select, is a hidden field, it's a pre-selected value and disabled attribute for the user.

That's why jquery on IE8 retrieves me the error.

The solution was:

my_lib.js

```
jQuery.ajax({
        data : jQuery('form').serialize(),
        url : '/'+action[1]+'/post_form',
        type : 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){
          if( $('#my_name_id').is('select') ) {
             $('#my_name_id').find('option').remove().end().append(data.select_options);
          }
});
```

Hope it helps somebody!

Answer (score 2):

You appear to be missing a semi-colon in your get_data function after `echo_data(data)`.

```
request.done(function(data) {
    if (data) echo_data(data) _loading.hide();
    _ads_listing.unmask();
});
```

Comment: Just wanted to add that Internet Explorer's debugger is extremely strict, you need to make sure that semi colons, trailing commas and etc are fixed otherwise IE will throw an error.

Comment: Thank you for you reply, but I am still getting the same error. Here is my changed code: http://pastebin.com/WqE3QyTg . Thank you for your help..

Comment: @lthibodeaux I updated my first post.. Please check it out. I still get an error.. Thank you.