# Edge Javascript localdatetime

Tags: javascript, windows, microsoft-edge

i have big problem with MS Edge Windows 10. We have cloud applicaton in our company. That application uses JavaScript function

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_tolocaletimestring

webdeveloper toolkit said `Console: SCRIPT655353: Unexpected call or access` and the application shows white blank page.

Not all Windows 10 computers have this problem. 
The IE 11 and Firefox do not have the problem.

All windows user profiles have the problem. I need to find a setting that causes the problem.

How can I locate the error?

Comment: Check this link, it might help you out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8263069/strange-jquery-error-in-ie-unexpected-call-to-method-or-property-access

Comment: I try to test your sample code with Edge 42 and Edge 44 version and code is working fine. See here. https://i.postimg.cc/bwPXzdPh/90.gif I suggest you to just try to run the above posted code on your machine to check whether it giving error or not. If issue persist than try to inform us which exact build of Win 10 and which exact version of Edge you are using currently. If you are using any older version than try to update with latest version may help to solve the issue. If issue is not producible with above code than it can be possible that some other code in your application cause this issue

Comment: Edge 42.171341.0

Comment: Windows 10.0.17134.590. It's a computer setting, but I do not know which is causing the problem. New computer works everything. Until either user data is migrated or computer modifications are made by the user, software, etc.

Comment: Try to reset or repair MS Edge may help to solve the issue. Repairing the browser won't affect anything, but resetting will remove your history, cookies, and any settings you might have changed. You'll find these options in Settings  > Apps > Microsoft Edge > Advanced Options. Ref: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4023560/windows-10-what-to-do-if-microsoft-edge-not-working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was Reg-Key in local machine. This key was migrated from another computer´s user profile. If you delete this key, then it works immediately.

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Time
```